# Whether TypeScript provide me a if guard on class properties?

Tags: typescript

I am working on an AngularJS2 TypeScript project. I defined below class:

```
@Injectable()
export class INService {
  public Event;
  public User;
  public API;

  constructor() {
    console.log('FBService instantiated.');
    if (IN) {
      this.Event = IN.Event;
      this.User = IN.User;
      this.API = IN.API;
    }
  }
}
```

In this class constructor, it will check whether the `IN` library exists or not, if yet, it will save the scoped methods in its own attributes. Now other places who need to use `IN` method will use it from this class. But other places have to check whether the attributes are null or not see below example:

```
if(this.inService.User){
     this.inService.User.authorize( ... )
}
```

Is there a way for me to get ride of the `if` check? Can I add the `if` check on the class `INService` itself? Or whether `TypeScript Interface` provide such feather?

In addition, whether I can add some logic when user calls the `this.inService.User` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

How about providing a default implementation?

```
if (IN) {
    this.Event = IN.Event;
    this.User = IN.User;
    this.API = IN.API;
}else{
    this.Event = {...} // same interface as IN.Event and provide empty implementation or anything else you want
    this.User = ...
    this.API = ...
}
```

Comment: I have to list all interface methods. Is there a better way to do that?